# Pertaining to random and non-repeating numbers

Tags: c#, .net, random

My code is supposed to generate random and non-repeating numbers, but when I print it it doesn't do it properly and sometimes it repeats itself. How can I fix?

```
Console.WriteLine("choose how many digits your password should be\nminimum 5 maximum 10 digits");
Console.Write("number of digits:");
int digit = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int[] passwordarray = new int[digit];
Random r = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < passwordarray.Length; i++)
{
    if (digit <= 10 && digit >= 5)
   {
        do
        {
            passwordarray[i] = r.Next(0, 10);
        } while (!(passwordarray.Contains(passwordarray[i])));
    }
    else
    {
       Console.WriteLine("your number of digits is less than 5 or more than 10");
    }
}
```

Comment: You add the digit first with ```passwordarray[i] = r.Next(0, 10);``` and then check the loop condition after adding the digit. Nothing in this code stops you from adding the same digit twice... just generate the random value, store it temporary in a variable, check if it is already in the array, and if its NOT in there, then you should add it. But you add the value first, and then check the condition...

Comment: Just *shuffle* array of `{0,1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}` and take required number of digits

Comment: You should probably validate the input as soon as you get it rather than inside a loop. Also, `int.Parse` with throw an exception if the input isn't an integer. Should probably use [`int.TryParse`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi_6pHPmPv5AhUYIDQIHUsTDJYQFnoECAIQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fdotnet%2Fapi%2Fsystem.int32.tryparse&usg=AOvVaw35Ul21c7qYu7DttNERjnwp) instead.

Comment: Why would you check for `digit` _inside_ the loop? Check for the password length just after the user inputs it.

Answer (score 2):

I restructured your code:

```cs
Console.WriteLine("choose how many digits your password should be\nminimum 5 maximum 10 digits");
Console.Write("number of digits:");
int digit = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int[] passwordarray = new int[digit];
Random r = new Random();

// check the digits first
if (digit <= 10 && digit >= 5)
{
    int tempVal;
    for (int i = 0; i < passwordarray.Length; i++)
    {
        // generate values until you have a value thats not in the array
        do
        {
            tempVal = r.Next(0, 10);
        } while (passwordarray.Contains(tempVal));

        // add the value
        passwordarray[i] = tempVal;
    }
}
```

Basically you want to check first if the digits are between 5 and 10, then iterate trough your array, generate random values until you have one that isn't in the password array yet, and add this value. I just restructured your code, I didn't run it.

EDIT: obviously there are better solutions to implement this behavior, like Dmitrys answer, I restructured the code just to show you where your logic is wrong